# Do you understand this deadlock?

Tags: python, multithreading, join, wxpython, deadlock

I'm using wxPython for my GUI. In the `AppLogic` class I have a worker thread that is run in a method of this very class.

This is the `GUI` class:

```
class GUI:
    _wx_app = None
    _main_window = None
    _app_logic = None

    def start(self):
        # bla bla bla
        self._main_window.Show()
        self._app_logic.begin()
        self._wx_app.MainLoop()

    def _cancel_listener(self):
        """Called from MainWindow, if the user has clicked the cancel
        button."""
        print("I'm leaving this scope.")
        self._app_logic.cancel()  # Should cancel the task done in
                                  # a second thread.

    def _status_listener(self, status_text):
        """Called often by the worker thread."""
        print("Here I am again.")
        if self._main_window.status.GetLabel() != status_text:
            self._main_window.status.SetLabel(status_text)
```

Here's the cancel method from the `AppLogic` class which is called by `_cancel_listener` from above:

```
    def cancel(self):
        self._shall_abort = True
        self._thread.join(self._some_time_out)
        assert self._thread.isAlive() == False
```

Somehow, there's a deadlock with `join` and `GetLabel` (and thus `MainLoop`?) involved, but I don't really understand what's going on. Does someone have more insight into this? That would be great!

Comment: 'Somehow, there's a deadlock with join' - not a huge surprise, TBH :(  join() is best avoided in GUI apps.  In non-GUI apps, join() is best avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All GUI toolkits have a main GUI thread. They all have special methods that allow you to manipulate the GUI widgets in a thread-safe way. In wxPython world, those methods are wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent. I don't see those anywhere in your example, so what you're doing is basically pausing the GUI thread or causing something "undefined" to occur.

Here are a couple of articles on threads and wxPython:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm summarizing: I'm blocking the GUI thread with `join` and the worker thread calls a listener the `GUI` class registered. +++ So why can't the call stack of the worker thread just contain the calls to `GetLabel` and subsequent ones, do it's work and return? Is there a thread synchronization point in the GUI framework that blocks, too?

Comment: I don't really understand, but if you're going to make direct calls to the wx main thread, then you're going to have issues. That's why I said you need to use threadsafe methods or just don't update the main loop until your other threads are done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm out of my field here, but I suspect wxPython works like other toolkits by sending messages to child windows via the GUI thread, then waiting for the answer. If this is the case, the GetLabel() or SetLabel() methods have to go through the main message loop (== GUI thread), and stop the calling thread until the answer comes in.

When you call cancel() from the GUI thread, it sets the abort variable, then waits for the other thread to end with `self._thread.join()`, so no further messages are processed until the other thread has halted. But the other thread keeps waiting for the answer to its GetLabel() message -> bingo!

Comment: I'm only considering the scope of `GUI` now. +++ I understand your explanation this way: `GetLabel` doesn't return because the GUI thread hangs at cancel. +++ But couldn't the stack just be made deeper? +++ This is what comes into my mind about this topic: `MainLoop` already stops because of this stack part: `MainLoop` > something in `MainWindow` > `_cancel_listener` > `cancel`. Therefore `GetLabel` can only wait 'til `MainLoop` decides to have processed the previous call chain. But that doesn't happen. +++ Is this attempted explanation correct? +++ Very complex! My brain is fried.