# Why does it have to be the context of the GUI thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

This is an excerpt from a source file of wxPython:

```
    """
    Create the output window if needed and write the string to it.
    If not called in the context of the gui thread then uses
    CallAfter to do the work there.
    """
```

How does this work internally? Why is it important that GUI related calls are not made by other threads directly?

Do you know of a chart or something that explains such GUI concepts in a short, simple way?

I would love, if I not had to read a novel to understand this issue so that I know how to choose my design.

---

**Edit:**

This is for a discussion below:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: There's no need for GUI code to support being called from multiple threads. To do so would require all sorts of synchronisation code to be added to the GUI framework. So almost all GUI frameworks insist on their clients only calling from the GUI thread. As a client of the framework it is almost irrelevant why the decision was made. It is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy. Think of a queue, wxPython has it's own internal Event-Queue, you cause wxPython to process it when calling MainLoop on your `app`, which will be called from the Main-Thread. So as whenever you modify a widget it will not interfere with the MainLoop which is processing the Event-Queue. But when you add Threads, more then one Thread is manipulating the GUI and/or the Event-Queue and GUI-access is not synchronized. 
That's where wx.CallAfter gets useful, it simply adds an pseudo-event to the Event-Queue, which will call your specified function, so it will be executed from the Main-Thread and just one Thread is accessing the GUI. Note, when your passed function takes a while to return the GUI will freeze, because no more events (like movement or clicks) are processed.

Related: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: "and GUI-access is not synchronized." - Can you tell me why this isn't done? Would it be too much effort or such kind of thing? Thanks for your explanation btw.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you why it isn't synchronized without guessing. If you want an answer you can ask on the wxPython mailinglist, RobinD e.g. can answer this question.

Comment: Your explanation was helpful for my understanding. But somehow I get to point where I don't understand anything anymore and I think: So a method like StaticText.GetLabel triggers to process a message in the main loop, or what? Can you clarify this, please?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the other Thread accesses the GUI (in any form) or the Event-Queue, they are both not synchronized (e.g. with locks found in the `threading` module). Think of a function which updates the text in a TextCtrl, while it is updating, another Thread calls GetValue, what do you expect GetValue to return? the text before, the text which is already updated or the complete new text? The latter would be the case, if the GUI access was synchronized, but without synchronization everything can happen.

Comment: Okay, I know this in context of the keyword _atomic_. +++ (If my questions confuse you: I came to this subject because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10549500/). There my GUI thread gets paused by join and then GetLabel is called.) Please look at the picture above that I uploaded. Can you agree to this?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your picture describes the optimal behaviour (everything is synchronized).

Comment: It describes what I thought is the current behaviour of wxPython. In my example in the other thread at Stackoverflow my GUI thread gets paused by join() and then GetLabel() is called (by another thread). THEN GetLabel() doesn't return, as if it waits for the GUI thread. So I concluded there has to be some thread checking and waiting somewhere in the call chain. It's just too unclear for me, why GetLabel blocks.

Comment: Are you sure GetLabel blocks? You're waiting until the Thread stops (join, called from the Main-Thread), while this happens no other action can be taken from the Main-Thread => the GUI "freezes" until thread.join returns.

Comment: Yes, I have two `print`s around a plain call to `GetLabel`. And when `join` was called by the GUI thread, the worker thread only prints the first text, that is blocks at the `GetLabel` in between.